# ubuntu error with librgba.so when using ' git commit --amend '

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

Getting this error on my ubuntu 10.04 box:

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "rgba": librgba.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

.. this is an alpha / coloring directory used with the command line ( to color things )

This particular error message pops up with git as well as when programming my arduino

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu console:

```
'sudo synaptic'
```

In synaptic GUI:
1. click “Origin” ( lower left)
2. select LP-PPA-erik-b-andersen-rgba-gtk/lucid ( upper left )
3. For each of the following packages (located top right )

> gtk2-engines-murrine
>   gtk2-module.rgba
>   libnautilus-extension-dev
>   murrine-themes
>  nautilus
>   nautilus-data

do this:

> -select package
>   -MENU>>Package>>Force Version ( ctrl+e ) 
>   -select package with 'ppa1' in the name
>   -click 'force version'

.....after all packages are selected to be running.....

4. click 'apply'

You should now no longer get the annoying error:
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "rgba": librgba.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be because of an unofficial [Gtk transparency PPA](https://launchpad.net/~erik-b-andersen/+archive/rgba-gtk).  If that's the case try [reverting back to the supported packages](http://www.khattam.info/solved-gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-rgba-librgba-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory-2010-03-13.html).

Comment: It looks like all the tutorials online suggest this edit.. which IS an option.  However, the edit i just posted allows me to keep the coloring in console.  Thanks anyways!